# Xcode keeps adding remote repo for no reason

Tags: xcode, git, svn

I have developed a Swift Package. During development I have added it to my app by dragging the folder to an Xcode window containing the app (as one does).

Obviously, the delete button is grayed out

[image]

The problem is that even after removing the Package from Xcode, the remote target stays in the list and cannot be deleted.

What I have tried

- editing the `.xccheckout` file (but it doesn't exist in my project)
- deleted derived data folder
- run `find ./ -name .svn -exec rm -rf {} \;` and do the same with `.git`
- manually searched for files containing the repo's name. This brought up hits in the `UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate` file which presumably contains information on what files have been opened, where the cursor was etc. So I wiped the file. Once I open the project again, it will recreate the file and out of nowhere adds references to the repo again.

Where else do I have to search? This is haunting me and I have no idea what through the head of the developer who added this "functionality" to xcode

What IS interesting is that if I change the name of the folder containing the project and then open the project, the entry disappears. Changing it back and opening the project again makes it show up again.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out to be the derived data folder - however, not in the way it usually is.

There was another folder in `Derived Data` with another project's name which may have been in the same location as the current project. Removing this project and its folder in the `Derived Data` solved the issue